# Interactor mouse events without disable rotation vtkActors

Tags: vtk

This code is a selector actor. Once one actor is selected it prints the high of the respective selected actor. the problem is that the rotation and dragging is disable in the interactor and I want to include it.

```
// Handle mouse events
class MouseInteractorStyle5 : public vtkInteractorStyleTrackballActor
{
    public:
    static MouseInteractorStyle5* New();
    vtkTypeMacro(MouseInteractorStyle5, vtkInteractorStyleTrackballActor);

    virtual void OnLeftButtonDown()
    {
        // Forward events
        vtkInteractorStyleTrackballActor::OnLeftButtonDown();

        for (auto it = actors.begin(); it != actors.end(); ++it)
        {
            if(this->InteractionProp == (*it))
            {
                std::cout << "Actor high: " << (*it)->GetMapper()->GetInput()->GetPoint(0)[2] << std::endl;
            }
        }

    }
    std::vector<vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor>> actors;
};

vtkStandardNewMacro(MouseInteractorStyle5);

void actorsMouseInteractor(const std::vector<vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor>> & actors)
{
    // A renderer and render window
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer> renderer =
      vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer>::New();
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow> renderWindow =
      vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow>::New();
    renderWindow->AddRenderer(renderer);


    // An interactor
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor> renderWindowInteractor =
      vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor>::New();
    renderWindowInteractor->SetRenderWindow(renderWindow);

    // Set the custom stype to use for interaction.
    vtkSmartPointer<MouseInteractorStyle5> style =
        vtkSmartPointer<MouseInteractorStyle5>::New();
    style->SetDefaultRenderer(renderer);
    style->actors = actors;

    renderWindowInteractor->SetInteractorStyle(style);

    renderer->AddActor(getPlatformActor());
    for (auto it = actors.begin(); it != actors.end(); ++it)
    {
        renderer->AddActor(*it);
    }
    renderer->SetBackground(.1, .2, .4);
    renderWindow->Render();
    renderWindow->SetSize(renderWindow->GetScreenSize());
    renderWindowInteractor->Start();
}
```

the output is for example the position in Z:

Actor high: 1.800

Comment: Do you want to rotate the individual actors or the camera? If it's the camera, you need to use vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera instead of vtkInteractorStyleTrackballActor.

Comment: Yes but I would like at the same time to select actors and it seems that the only way it is with vtkInteractorStyleTrackballActor, isn't it?

Comment: Not necessarily. Use a vtkPropPicker to do it instead.